# Como obtener el valor seleccionado de un ComboBox

Tags: c#, combobox

necesito obtener el valor seleccionado de un combobox en una variable de tipo string.
En este caso tengo un combobox que contiene las formas de pago como **EFECTIVO/CREDITO**,que lleno de la base de datos, no necesito el ID sino el valor seleccionado.
intenté hacer de esta forma, pero no logré obtener el valor.

```
string formaPago = Convert.ToString(cboFormaPago.SelectedItem);
string formaPago= cboFormaPago.SelectedItem.ToString();
```

Comment: Usas entityframework?

Answer (score 0):

Lo realizarías de esta forma obteniendo el objeto [ComboBoxItem](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.comboboxitem?view=net-5.0) :

```
ComboBoxItem comboItem = (ComboBoxItem) cboFormaPago.SelectedItem;
string formaPago = comboItem.Content.ToString();
```

Answer (score -1):

Yo lo hago así:

```
FormaDePago = "" + cboFormaDePago.GetItemText(cboFormaDePago.SelectedItem);
```

con SelectedItem esta indicando que elemento esta seleccionado y ese es el que de asigna a mis variable forma de pago.

Comment: Considera explicar tu código para que otros usuarios se puedan guiar